# ProgressTask, of an in a Swing embedded JavaFx application, starts late

Tags: javafx

I´m embedding serveral JavaFx Panels into a Swing application, these running also quite well. Now i´d like to add a progressbar on starting the plugin and here is my problem. The progressbar appears very late.

This is the class i use for embedding.

```
private ProgressIndicator indicator;
private Stage stage;
private Scene scene;
private BorderPane root;

public FxIOGuiProgressTask() {
    initGui();
    startJfxProgressTask();
}

private void startJfxProgressTask() {

    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            try {
                load();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logException(ex);
                return null;
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                try {
                    finished();
                    stage.close();
                    afterFinishedInformation();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    logException(ex);
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}

protected abstract void load() throws Exception;

protected abstract void finished() throws Exception;

public void afterFinishedInformation() {
}

private void initGui() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        indicator.setMaxSize(150, 150);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Wird geladen...");
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        root = new BorderPane(indicator);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
        scene = new Scene(root, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    });
}
```

If i move the finished() method out of the Platform.runLater(), and place it after the load() method, an exception occurs "Not on FX application thread".

Maybee someone knows an answer.

Comment: If `FxIOGuiProgressTask()` is called on the FX thread you could get rid of the `Platform.runLater()` in `initGui()` and build the UI inline. `startJfxProgressTask();` would be called after all that was done.

If `FxIOGuiProgressTask()` is not on the FX thread you could move the call to `startJfxProgressTask();` to just after `stage.show()` in the `Platform.runLater()` call in `initGui()`. Either way it's about making sure the two jobs are run in the order you want, at the moment it's most likely your task starting first.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has helped a lot. The second case is mine, I still have no FxThread at this time. So I have inserted the call for the `startJfxProgressTask ()` method after `stage.show ()` and it works. 
Actually clear, but I have not seen it.
You are my hero ....